# new azure port will not open

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

Some time back I created an Azure VM and needed to open some ports. I did so by creating a security group and added the appropriate inbound rules to open the ports. Also I created an inbound rule in the VM firewall (Windows server 20216).

Everything works - so far.

Then I needed to add one more port, but this new port will not open?! I tried different ports just to "test" things. But no luck. 
To make this even more "crazy" I changed the ports that works to a range instead of a specific port but that ALSO does not work.

The port that work is 58081. So I change the inbound rule to 58081-50890. I did that in the windows firewall and the inbound rule in the security group.
The port 58081 still works, but ports 58082 and up does NOT work.

I tried to change this specific inbound rule to another port. That will make port 58081 NOT work, but the port I changed to will ALSO not work !! But if I change it back to 58081 then that port will start working again.

The logic tells me that I'm missing a part. But what?

I'm pulling my hair on this one !!

Comment: It sounds like your saying that you created firewall rules in Azure on....a network security group?...and/or are using windows firewall on server 2016?  are you using a Security Group in Azure or a Network Security Group?

Comment: Sorry - I'll close this ticket. I was editing a NSG that was attached to another VM that I was having problems with.